# What is the most efficient Inter communication between 2 Threads (Socket Thread and Main Thread)?

Tags: multithreading, performance, sockets, communication, postmessage

We do have a Thread reading data from multiple Sockets by using async IO with WSARecvFrom() and IoCompletionPort.

The received Data (packet size about 1500 Byte) should be processed by the Main Thread. The Main Thread handles also all other sync stuff.

If the Main Thread is associated with a Window and we use PostMessage() to send a Message to that Window it uses very much time till the Main Window thread get the Message via GetMessage() and can Process the Data. If we should process a lot of Network Messages this Method is not usable.

Would PostThreadMessage() in Socket Thread and GetMessage() in Main Thread have better performance ?

Would SetEvent () in Socket Thread and WaitForMultipleObjects () in Main Thread have better performance ?

Is there a more efficient way for signaling the arrival of the data to the Main Thread ?

Are there any Win32 synchronisation functions what also directly could send the Data to be processed by the Main Thread without having an application buffer guarded by semaphores ?

Comment: You could push data from reading thread into in-memory buffer and then signal processing thread (via conditional variable) to start working on data. Data to be protected by lock/mutex. PostThreadMessage() will copy data around, which might be expensive

Comment: Are you using 2 threads in the same program/process or do you have 2 different processes? Also, it would help to know the programming languague you're working with.

Comment: We do have one process including the 2 threads. The programming language is c/c++, the application is a native win32 Service.

Comment: 'we use PostMessage() to send a Message to that Window it uses very much time till the Main Window thread get the Message via GetMessage() and can Process the Data' - what?  You are posting a buffer instance/pointer to a Windows Message Queue.  What could be faster?  Why do you perceive it as slow?

Comment: PostThreadMessage() does not copy any kind of bulk data.

Comment: When we Post a lot of Messages using PostMessage() it seems to take a long time (about 1 Second) till the messages are seen in the Main Thread. This happens only on some higher system load. So I'm not shure if the Message Loop, the posting mechanism or the Main Thread's processing stuff is the Problem.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, no.  There is no faster mechanism available than PostMessage(), PostThreadMessage(), QueueUserAPC etc. inter-thread comms calls.

The time taken for such calls to transfer a buffer pointer or 'this' instance pointer is normally swamped by the large amount of time required to render such data onto a GUI component.

If you have loaded up your main thread with a pile of non-GUI activity that prevents the prompt handling of messages, or you are posting messages faster than the GUI thread can reasonably consume them, then you have a big problem.

If the latency of PostMessage() is actually the root cause of your problem, (which I doubt), then you could maybe aggregate the buffers into a container object and PostMessage that instead, so improving the overall bandwidth of the posted messages.

> Would SetEvent () in Socket Thread and WaitForMultipleObjects () in
>   Main Thread have better performance ?

I suspect not noticeably. It would have to be WaitForMultipleObjects(Ex), to handle the 'normal' GUI messages as well as your stuff.  It won't help if the root cause is an main thread that is overloaded for other reasons, or if messages are posted faster than you can handle them.